# Python two variables one input

Tags: python

I want to save an user input directly into two variables like:

```
n,k = input("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein: " )

print(n)
print(k)
```

n and k should print the same value.

Comment: Why do you tag this with Java?

Comment: That would be `n = k = ...`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a *double assignment*:

```
n = k = input("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein: " )
```

Your `n,k = ...` however **is *iterable unpacking***: only if the user would enter two characters, this would not error: in that case the first character would be assigned to `n`, and the second character to `k`. So if you would have written `fo`, then `n` would have value `'f'` and `k` would have value `'o'`. But for all other cases, this would fail.

Be careful however with *mutable objects*: if you write:

```
a = b = [1,4,2,5]
```

Then **both variables refer to the same list object**. Only **one list is constructed**. And if you modify the list through `a`, then you will see the difference through `b` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
n = k = input("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein: " )
```

Answer (score 1):

for same value in two variable:

```
n = k = input("enter two values:")
```

for two value in two variable:

```
n, k = input("enter two values:").split(' ')
```